# Soap api methods are not returning anything / Status; waiting for activation

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, soap-client

I'm working on small application which should communicate with soap api.

Here is the code:

```
namespace Demo1._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                makeSoapCall();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void makeSoapCall()
        {
            EnventoryWebserviceClient client = new EnventoryWebserviceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "some@thing.com";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "somePass!";

            var method1 = client.contentReportAsync();
            var method2 = client.deleteSoapFlagsAsync();
            var method3 = client.getSoapFlagsAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Issue here is that I couldt get any response from that methods, client is successfully connected and I dont get any exceptions.

When I debug this I can see this informations:
[image]

Im pretty new to programming, whats "issue" here? How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance

P.S

I have tried to await them but than I dont know how to call this method in `Main` method snce I must declare `makeSoapCall` method as `async`

Cheers

Comment: Looks like those methods return a Task. You can try await client.contentReportAsync() or add them to a list and await all?

Comment: If contentReportAsync,deleteSoapFlagsAsync and getSoapFlagsAsync async then you need to await them (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling async methods in your SOAP api.
Async method behave different than synchronous methods, which means that async methods will not by default wait for the result until it moves on to the next line.

Below you have two methods of handling async methods.

**First method:**

This is the most straight forward way to make your async method behave as a synchronous one. As the 'await' will make sure you get the result before moving on to the next line.

**Second method:**

If each method takes a while to call, you can run them parallel.
Which means that if each method takes 7 seconds, you dont have to wait 21 seconds until all of them have finished.

Instead you can start the calls at the same time and only wait 7 seconds in total.

```
// First Method
var method1 = await client.contentReportAsync();
var method2 = await client.deleteSoapFlagsAsync();
var method3 = await client.getSoapFlagsAsync();

// Second Method
var method1 = client.contentReportAsync();
var method2 = client.deleteSoapFlagsAsync();
var method3 = client.getSoapFlagsAsync();

Task[] tasks = { method1, method2, method3 };
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// To access the result in this way, use ".Result"
var result = method1.Result;
```

Your full code example could look something like the following (note the async in the method declaration):

```
namespace Demo1._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                await makeSoapCall();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public async static void makeSoapCall()
        {
            EnventoryWebserviceClient client = new EnventoryWebserviceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "some@thing.com";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "somePass!";

            var method1 = await client.contentReportAsync();
            var method2 = await client.deleteSoapFlagsAsync();
            var method3 = await client.getSoapFlagsAsync();
        }
    }
}
```